# How to build a desktop gadget for Windows XP?

Tags: .net, wpf, windows-xp, windows-desktop-gadgets

I want to build a desktop gadget for Windows XP — something like [Desktop Sidebar](http://www.desktopsidebar.com/download.html)

Is it possible to develop an application using WPF/Silverlight in .NET that can behave as a gadget to display information from webservices?

OR

Please suggest any alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gadgets were introduced in Windows Vista, so they didn't exist in XP. You can write an application that implements similar functionality (although it will be more difficult because of the lack of OS support) using any Windows development language that supports WinXP.

Answer (score 1):

You could check autoit (http://www.autoitscript.com) Maybe not the best solution but it works, i've made som widgets using that language (basic like)

It's very simple and they have good documentation as well